# Dealing with char arrays in C++

Tags: c++

I have this C-styled piece of initialization code:

```
const char * const vlc_args[] =
{
    "-I", "dummy",
    "--ignore-config",
    "--extraintf=logger",
    "--verbose=2"
    "--plugin-path=/usr/lib/vlc"
};
//tricky calculation of the char space used
libvlc_new(sizeof(vlc_args)/sizeof(vlc_args[0]), vlc_args, &exc);
```

Since I need to make the `--plugin-path` parameter dynamic, I can't use a static array anymore. So I came up with a C++ alternative:

```
std::string pluginpath = "test";
libvlc_exception_t exc;

std::vector<std::string> args;
args.push_back("-I");
args.push_back("dummy");
args.push_back("--ignore-config");
args.push_back("--extraintf=logger");
args.push_back("--verbose=2");
args.push_back("--ipv4");
args.push_back("--plugin-path=" + pluginpath);

std::string combinedString;
for (size_t idx = 0; idx < args.size(); ++idx)
{
    combinedString.append(args[idx]);
    combinedString.resize(combinedString.size() + 1);
    combinedString[combinedString.size() - 1] = 0;
}
combinedString.resize(combinedString.size() + 1);
combinedString[combinedString.size() - 1] = 0;

size_t size = combinedString.size();
const char * data = combinedString.c_str();
libvlc_new(size, &data, &exc); // => error occurs here (not at end of scope or anything)
```

But this results in a segmentation fault. So there must be an error in my code, which I can't seem to find.. Can anyone spot it?

**Solved!**
Thanks to Joseph Grahn and Jason Orendorff. My idea on the memory layout of the C-style array was wrong. I thought all data was organized as a big sequential block. In reality it's a list of pointers to the first character of each individual string.

This code works:

```
std::vector<const char*> charArgs;
for (size_t idx = 0; idx < args.size(); ++idx)
{
    charArgs.push_back(&(args[idx][0]));
}
mVLCInstance = libvlc_new(charArgs.size(),
                          &charArgs[0],
                          &mVLCException);
```

Comment: Run it in a debugger and tell us what line it segfaults on.

Comment: It segfaults in object code without debugging symbols. In my code this happens during the libvlc_new call.

Comment: Why are you passing &data to the libvlc_new function?  In the original code, the 2nd parameter is of type const char *, now you are passing const char **.  Remove the "&" from the 2nd parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Josef Grahn is right: the API wants an actual array of pointers.

If you don't need to add arguments programmatically, you can just go back to using an array:

```
std::string pluginpath = "test";
std::string pluginpath_arg = "--plugin-path=" + pluginpath;
const char *args[] = {
    "-I", dummy, "--ignore-config", ..., pluginpath_arg.c_str()
    };

libvlc_exception_t exc;
libvlc_new(sizeof(args) / sizeof(args[0]), args, &exc);
```

**EDIT**: There might *also* be a problem with using `c_str()` here. This is true if VLC keeps the pointer and uses it again later; I can't tell if that's the case from the docs.

Comment: I remember reading that the Google code guidelines dictate using sizeof(args[0]) instead of sizeof(char) so it doesn't need to be changed (or forgotten) in case the data type changes (wchar_t for example).

Comment: Thanks Jason, your answer was the one that got me thinking in the right way.

Comment: epatel: Good eye, I meant `sizeof(args[0])`.

Answer (score 4):

You are appending all arguments into a single string, then you pass a pointer to the const char * string to libvlc_new as if it were an array of char *.

(I'm not sure this is the problem, but it seems a bit strange.)

Comment: How does is it different from an array of char*? Isn't the memory layout in both cases the same?

Comment: No, "const char * const vlc_args[]" is an array of pointers.  There aren't any pointers in the single string.

Comment: I don't know what libvlc expects, but for program arguments as in main(), you are supposed to be able to do: argv[3] to get a const char * to the forth argument, for example. In your case that would yield a wild pointer somewhere on the stack (above where variable data resides).

Answer (score 1):

## Regarding the segmentation violation

**No solution, as there will probably be more problems**

You are sending only 1 string in. (not sure if it is allowed by `libvlc_new`) So the first parameter should be set to 1, ie `size = 1`. I believe this will solve the segmentation problem. But I doubt `libvlc_new` can be called with just one line of multiple parameters.

In the original code `sizeof(vlc_args)/sizeof(vlc_args[0])` will have the number of parameters as entries in the vector. In your example equal 6.

Your code

```
size_t size = combinedString.size(); // a long string, size >> 1
const char * data = combinedString.c_str(); // data is a pointer to the string

libvlc_new(size, &data, &exc);

// size should be 1 because data is like an array with only one string. 
// &data is the adress to the "array" so to speak. If size > 1 the function
// will try to read pass the only string available in this "array"
```

I think Jason Orendorff has a good solution to fix it all...

Answer (score 1):

The library call expects a pointer to an array of `const char*` (that is several pointers), but you pass it a single pointer. That more characters got appended to the end of that string doesn't matter.

To dynamically build an array of the required pointers you could use another `vector`:

```
// store c_str() pointers in vector
std::vector<const char*> combined;
for (size_t idx = 0; idx < args.size(); ++idx) {
    combined.push_back(args[idx].c_str());
}

// pass pointer to begin of array (it is guaranteed that the contents of a vector
// are stored in a continuous memory area)
libvlc_new(combined.size(), &(combined[0]), &exc);
```

[Jason Orendorff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877579/dealing-with-char-arrays-in-c/1877665#1877665)'s remark is also valid here: This will not work if `libvlc_new` stores the passed pointer internally for later use.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
libvlc_new(size, data, &exc);
```

instead of

```
libvlc_new(size, &data, &exc);
```

It seems you use the null bytes to make the string act like an array of characters, but then you pass a pointer to the char* "array" instead of just the array.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue; I wanted to dynamicly generate the arguments, but in a safe c++ way.

The solution I hit on was to use the unique_ptr<[]> new to C++ 11. For example:

```
unique_ptr<char *[]> vlc_argv;
int vlc_argc;
...
auto vlc(libvlc_new(vlc_argc, vlc_argv.get()));
```

This gives me a nice RAII object to hold my arguments in that I can still pass into libvlc_new(). Since the arguments are raw pointers in argv, managed by the OS, we can just use those in our vlc_argv directly.

As a further example assume I process the first few args out of `argv` (somewhere in the "..." area above), and want to pass everything from `next_arg` on to libvlc_new():

```
vlc_argv = std::unique_ptr<char *[]>(new char *[2 + argc - next_arg]);
vlc_argv[0] = argv[0];
for (vlc_argc=1; vlc_argc <= argc - next_arg; vlc_argc++) {
    vlc_argv[vlc_argc] = argv[next_arg + vlc_argc - 1];
}
vlc_argv[vlc_argc] = 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is due to the use of c_str() and storing the pointer.

See [stringstream, string, and char* conversion confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374468/c-stringstream-string-and-char-conversion-confusion)

*EDIT* Forget what I said... it was late... see the comments :)

Comment: This situation is different from using a stringstream incorrectly (ss.str().c_str()) because in my string object is an l-value.

Comment: The pointer returned by `combinedString.c_str()` is valid until `combinedString` is modified or destroyed.