# Turning temporary stringstream to c_str() in single statement

Tags: c++, string, stringstream, temporary

Consider the following function:

```
void f(const char* str);
```

Suppose I want to generate a string using stringstream and pass it to this function.  If I want to do it in one statement, I might try:

```
f((std::ostringstream() << "Value: " << 5).str().c_str()); // error
```

This gives an error: 'str()' is not a member of 'basic_ostream'.  OK, so operator<< is returning ostream instead of ostringstream - how about casting it back to an ostringstream?

1) Is this cast safe?

```
f(static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(std::ostringstream() << "Value: " << 5).str().c_str()); // incorrect output
```

Now with this, it turns out for the operator<<("Value: ") call, it's actually calling ostream's operator<<(void*) and printing a hex address.  This is wrong, I want the text.

2) Why does operator<< on the temporary std::ostringstream() call the ostream operator?  Surely the temporary has a type of 'ostringstream' not 'ostream'?

I can cast the temporary to force the correct operator call too!

```
f(static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(std::ostringstream()) << "Value: " << 5).str().c_str());
```

*This appears to work* and passes "Value: 5" to f().

3) Am I relying on undefined behavior now?  The casts look unusual.

---

I'm aware the best alternative is something like this:

```
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << "Value: " << 5;
f(ss.str().c_str());
```

...but I'm interested in the behavior of doing it in one line.  Suppose someone wanted to make a (dubious) macro:

```
#define make_temporary_cstr(x) (static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(std::ostringstream()) << x).str().c_str())

// ...

f(make_temporary_cstr("Value: " << 5));
```

Would this function as expected?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stringstream, string, and char\* conversion confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374468/stringstream-string-and-char-conversion-confusion).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You cannot cast the temporary stream to `std::ostringstream&`. It is ill-formed (the compiler must tell you that it is wrong). The following can do it, though:

```
f(static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(
  std::ostringstream().seekp(0) << "Value: " << 5).str().c_str());
```

That of course is ugly. But it shows how it can work. `seekp` is a member function returning a `std::ostream&`. Would probably better to write this generally

```
template<typename T>
struct lval { T t; T &getlval() { return t; } };

f(static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(
  lval<std::ostringstream>().getlval() << "Value: " << 5).str().c_str());
```

The reason that without anything it takes the `void*`, is because that `operator<<` is a member-function. The `operator<<` that takes a `char const*` is not.

Comment: Your snippet with seekp(0) returns an empty string for me - but the lval template appears to work correctly.  That relies fully on defined behavior then, and would be portable?

Comment: @Ashley, sure it's all defined.

Comment: Could lval have an conversion operator to T&, avoiding the function call? (or perhaps the compiler doesn't pick up that operator automatically...)

Comment: @Macus, yep that wouldn't work. In free operators, template argument deduction would fail. And for member operators, those wouldn't be found in the first place. The conversion function isn't taken.

Comment: I don't get it. Ok, it compiles eventually. But is it going to really work? The result of the expression is going to be const char*, but to what is this pointer going to point? Is it guaranteed that the temporary ostringstream().str() instance still exists when the f() is being executed and the pointer passed to f is valid?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Visual Studio 2012 sets the failbit when calling `seekp(0)` on a fresh `ostringstream`

Answer (score 3):

A temporary cannot be passed as a non-const reference to a function, that's why it does not find the correct streaming operator and instead takes the one with void* argument (it is a member function and thus calling it on a temporary is OK).

What comes to getting around the limitations by casting, I have a feeling that it is in fact UB, but I cannot say for sure. Someone else will surely quote the standard.

Comment: I'm not passing the temporary ostringstream to f() - I'm only passing the result of c_str(), which is const (if it matters).  Besides, even so, what about that means it picks the void* argument?  What's different about it that allows it to be picked but not the const char* argument?

Comment: You are trying to pass a temporary ostringstream to ostream& operator<<(ostream&, char const*) and that fails (without the cast you  made to fix it). ostream& ostream::operator<<(void const*) can be picked because it is a member function and calling member functions of temporaries is permitted.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using a C++11 lambda function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

void f(const char * str)
{
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}

std::string str(void (*populate)(std::ostream &))
{
    std::ostringstream stream;
    populate(stream);
    return stream.str();
}

int main(int argc, char * * args)
{
    f(str([](std::ostream & ss){ ss << "Value: " << 5;  }).c_str());
    return 0;
}

// g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main
// ./main
// Value: 5
```

Comment: `#define TO_STR(MAC) ([=]{std::stringstream ss; ss << MAC; return std::string(ss.str());})()`

Answer (score 1):

Since C++17 we have folding expressions for templates that can be used to make generic string formatter that can accept everything that have stream support:

```
template <class... Args>
std::string format(Args &&... args)
{
    std::ostringstream ostr;

    (ostr << ... << args);

    return ostr.str();
}
```

The you can use it like: `format("Int number: ", 42, " Float number: ", 3.14).c_str()`.

In C++20 [std::format](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) is coming.

Answer (score 0):

If you like one_lined statements you can write:

```
// void f(const char* str); 
f(static_cast<ostringstream*>(&(ostringstream() << "Value: " << 5))->str());
```

However you should prefer easier to maintain code as:

```
template <typename V>
  string NumberValue(V val)
  {
     ostringstream ss;
     ss << "Value: " << val;
     return ss.str();
  }
f(NumberValue(5));
```

Comment: The one-liner you have suggested is wrong and would not work for all cases.

Answer (score 0):

I use something a bit like this for logging.

```
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

const char *log_text(ostringstream &os, ostream &theSame)
{
  static string ret; // Static so it persists after the call
  ret = os.str();
  os.str(""); // Truncate so I can re-use the stream
  return ret.c_str();
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ostringstream  ss;
  cout << log_text(ss, ss << "My first message") << endl;
  cout << log_text(ss, ss << "Another message") << endl;
}
```

Output:

My first message

Another message

Comment: Why convert to `const char *` when you can insert `std::string` into a stream?