# Convert boost::uuid to char*

Tags: c++, boost, uuid

I am looking to convert a boost::uuid to a const char*.    What is the correct syntax for the conversion?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can do this a bit easier using boost::lexical_cast that uses a std::stringstream under the hood.

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp>

const std::string tmp = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(theUuid);
const char * value = tmp.c_str();
```

Comment: after reading the boost documentation it seems to me that this answer is correct, however as per the documentation also indicates that to_string and to_wstring functions provided by boost::uuids is likely faster than boost::lexical_cast.  [link](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/uuid/uuid.html)

Answer (score 65):

Just in case, there is also `boost::uuids::to_string`, that works as follows:

```
#include <boost/uuid/uuid.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp>

boost::uuids::uuid a = ...;
const std::string tmp = boost::uuids::to_string(a);
const char* value = tmp.c_str();
```

Comment: For people working with ancient boost versions: This method is introduced in 1.44. See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp

Answer (score 11):

You can include `<boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp>` and then use the operators to convert a uuid into a `std::stringstream`.  From there, it's a standard conversion to a `const char*` as needed.

For details, see [the Input and Output second of the Uuid documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/uuid/uuid.html).

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << theUuid;

const std::string tmp = ss.str();
const char * value = tmp.c_str();
```

(For details on why you need the "tmp" string, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374468/c-stringstream-string-and-char-conversion-confusion/1374485#1374485).)

Answer (score 1):

You use the stream functions in boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp.

```
boost::uuids::uuid u;

std::stringstream ss;
ss << u;
ss >> u;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
boost::uuids::uuid u;

const char* UUID = boost::uuids::to_string(u).c_str();
```

It is possible to do a simple and quick conversion.

Comment: This would lead to UB, if to_string returns temporary.