# how to pass C++ variable in command attribute of button in C++/Tk?

Tags: c++, tk-toolkit

I'm newbie in C++/Tk and want to pass variable which is defined in C++ to command attribute in button.
 Herewith I'm posting code snippet.

```
int eoutputvar ;

stringstream ss ;
string setquery ;

ss.str( "set eoutputvar 10" ) ;
setquery = ss.str() ;

entry(".eoutput") -textvariable(eoutputvar) -width(20) ;

button(".b1") -text("click it") -command( setquery );
pack(".eoutput" ) -side("left") ;
```

My objective here is to set eoutputvar of entry widget when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your variables as `extern "C"`.

```
extern "C" {
  int eoutputvar;
  char *setquery;
}
```

The `setquery` parameter also needs to be a "C" variable and can't be declared as a `string`.   So as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8765574/how-to-put-stringstream-contents-into-char-type-instead-string-type):

```
setquery = ss.c_str();
```

Comment: No, its just not working yet. I've also tried namespace declaration.

Comment: Sorry, missed the changes needed for `setquery`.   All variables that get passed to the Tcl/Tk routines will need to have "C" linkage.

Comment: thanks for giving your inputs. But, this fix is also not working as it says: c_str is not a member of stringstream. it will be great help if you can provide a solution for this as I'm googling  for it from many days.