# C++ stringstream concatenate query

Tags: c++, string

The code is supposed to concatenate argv[1] with .txt , and with _r.txt .

```
std::stringstream sstm;
std::stringstream sstm_r;

sstm<<argv[1]<<".txt";
sstm_r<<argv[1]<<"_r.txt";

const char* result = sstm.str().c_str();
const char* result_r = sstm_r.str().c_str();

fs.open(result);
fs_r.open(result_r);

cout<<result<<endl;
cout<<result_r<<endl;
```

But what it does is , 
when i enter "abc" as argv[1] , it gives me , result as "abc_r.tx0" and result_r also same "abc_r.tx0" .What is the correct way to do this and why is this wrong .

Comment: because of c_str(), is it not a legacy element from c ?

Comment: Something's fishy in your question. The code has ".txt" while the text has ".tx0". Are you sure you're providing correct/up-to-date information in the question?

Comment: `sstm.str()` is a temporary string and so is `sstm.str().c_str()`. The're both only valid until the end of expression, yet you're storing the c_str pointer and later accesing it. You've got undefined behaviour.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze yes i am sure .

Comment: @rajat how can `c_str()` be legacy `C` if `std::string` didn't exist in C?

Comment: ohk , it might not be . i was not sure , thanks for editing .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `std::string` instances to which the pointers returned by `c_str()` are associated will be destroyed leaving `result` and `result_r` as dangling pointers, resulting in undefined behaviour. You need to save the `std::string` instances if you want to use `c_str()`:

```
const std::string result(sstm.str());

fs.open(result.c_str());  /* If this is an fstream from C++11 you
                             can pass a 'std::string' instead of a
                             'const char*'. */
```

Comment: Sry this , does not work well . It gives me a trailing question mark at the end of the filename . what it causing this problem .

Comment: @rajat, assuming `argv[1]` is populated the code is correct. See http://ideone.com/alBG9 for demo.

Comment: it can't depend on how argv[1] is populated because i am getting question mark at the end of the file name not in between as i am embedding .txt like this sstm<<argv[1]<<".txt";

Comment: could you please try and see if you are getting the same problem if you write a file .

Answer (score 3):

Work with the strings like this:

```
{
  const std::string& tmp = stringstream.str();
  const char* cstr = tmp.c_str();
}
```

This is taken from [another exchange here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374468/c-stringstream-string-and-char-conversion-confusion).