# Converting string to char pointer returns an empty string

Tags: c++

I convert the stringstream's string to char pointer but it writes empty string.
Why does it fail?

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "de12mu";
char* msg = (char*)ss.str().c_str();
std::cout << "msg: " << msg << " " << strlen(msg) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Undefined behaviour if I ever saw it. By the way, first related question on the right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374468/c-stringstream-string-and-char-conversion-confusion?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

It's because your call to `ss.str()` returns a *temporary* string, and when you then get a pointer to that temporary string it will not be valid after the statement is done.

Using that pointer after the temporary string is destroyed is *undefined behavior*.

Also note that the `c_str` function returns `const char*`.