# C++ Odd behaviour with ostringstream

Tags: c++, stl, ostringstream

Is there any explanation in the standard for the below behavior?

The following code:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ostringstream os1;
    ostringstream os2;

    os1 << 1 << " " << 2;
    os2 << 1 << " " << 2 << " " << 3;

    const char *p = os1.str().c_str();

    cout << os2.str() << endl;
    cout << p << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

displays the output:

```
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

However, I would expect it to display:

```
1 2 3
1 2
```

It looks like os1 object is somehow influenced by os2, if I remove the os2.str() call, example behaves correctly.

I have tried the example if Solaris Studio 12.2 and G++ 4.8.1 and both behave in the same way.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Weird, this code prints "1 2 3\n1 2\n" on my machine w/ g++.

Comment: Try here: http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp_online.php

Comment: @jma127 I get the same strange results using g++ 4.8.1 on Debian like P.An.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const char *p = os1.str().c_str();
```

Here is the problem, in the above line.

`os1.str()` returns a temporary string object by copying the internal string buffer. And you're taking `.c_str()` of the temporary object, which gets destroyed at the end of the full expression. The result is, `p` points to the destroyed object when you take it to print using `std::cout`.

That is, your program invokes undefined behavior (UB).

Try this:

```
auto s = os1.str();  
const char *p = s.c_str(); //s is not a temporary object anymore!
```

Now it gives [correct output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f13b74cf97beca5a) (and this is [your code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef12ba78b0fd9235) — luckily even coliru gives the same output as you observed on your machine. *Note that this output is **not** guaranteed though* precisely because the code invokes UB.).

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue has to do with retaining the pointer returned by `c_str()`.

`ostringstream::str()` is returning a temporary string object, and you are saving a pointer to it's internal `char` array.  But once that line has executed, the returned string object will be deleted.  So your pointer will be invalid.

If you want to keep a c_str pointer around for some reason, you would need to also keep a copy of the string:

```
string s = os1.str();
const char *p = s.c_str();

cout << os2.str() << endl;
cout << p << endl;
```

Comment: It looks like keeping a reference also work, if I change the code in the following way, it displays properly:                                                               const std::string& s = os1.str();
    const char *p = s.c_str();

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is here:
[stringstream, string, and char* conversion confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374468/c-stringstream-string-and-char-conversion-confusion?rq=1)

stringstream.str() returns a temporary string object that's destroyed at the end of the full expression. If you get a pointer to a C string from that (stringstream.str().c_str()), it will point to a string which is deleted where the statement ends.