# string.c_str() outputs gibberish - but only sometimes

Tags: c++

I'm writing a short OpenGL-program, and need to import the shader source, which I use the following code for (OpenGL wants the shader source as a c-string):

```
    std::ifstream t("GLshader.vert");
    if (!t.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "vertex shader open failed" << std::endl;
    }
    std::stringstream buffer;
    buffer << t.rdbuf();


    const char* source = buffer.str().c_str();
    std::string s = buffer.str().c_str();
    std::cerr << "vs string :" << std::endl << s << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "vs source:" << std::endl << source << std::endl;
```

What has me really stumped is the fact that *sometimes* everything is fine, and the last two lines of code output the same text. *Sometimes* however, for some reason, the output is instead this:

```
vs string:
/* actual shader code*/
#version 330 core

layout(location=0) in vec3 position;

out vec3 pos;
out vec2 texcoord;

void main(){
  pos = position;
  texcoord = (position.xy +1.f) / 2.f;
  gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0f);
}

vs source:
@ð4
```

The printouts, as well as the string, is there because I kept getting shader compilation errors (again, *sometimes*), and thought it might be some weird concurrency issue with reading the file. Obviously that works fine, but for some reason the c-string creation sometimes fails.

The function is called in a .dll, and I'm using visual studio. (I've run the .exe outside of VS, and the problem occurs there as well)

I'm really out of ideas here, anyone have an answer?

Comment: This may shed some light as well:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21534682/stringstreamstr-copy-lifetime

Comment: Hmm, wow, nope, I would never have figured that out. Now that you've told me, it is, as with the best problems, obvious. Thanks!

Comment: Prefer `std::string s = buffer;` since they are the same type.