# Cannot convert std::stringstream<char> to const char*

Tags: c++, string

I tried to run command with help of system() function, forwarding argument as in code below:

```
std::stringstream volume_control;
int volume_value = 5;
volume_control << "/usr/bin/amixer cset numid=1 " << volume_value << std::endl;
system(volume_control.str());
```

It doesn't work, because of unsuccessful conversion of std::stringstream to const char*.

I know that in std::string case I have method std::c_string() and If I'm right it returns exactly what I need const char* type, but in this case of stringstream that method does not exist. So what to do?

Answer (score 4):

[`volume_control.str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str) returns a `std::string` type. You need to call [`std::string::c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) or [`std::string::data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) method on it.

A google search would have easily given you the answer.

```
system(volume_control.str().c_str());
```

Comment: Your answer is wrong, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1374485 for details.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [c_str](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) method on `string` returned from `str` method.

```
system(volume_control.str().c_str());
```

Comment: @ForEveR Oops, you are right! The linked case was a different issue! Sorry & thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this link
[stringstream, string, and char* conversion confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374468/stringstream-string-and-char-conversion-confusion)

`{ const std::string& tmp = stringstream.str();    const char* cstr = tmp.c_str(); }`